# Is $det (A-A^T) = 0$ for a $n \times n$ matrix? ($n$ odd)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have the following problem:
We have a $n \times n$ matrix where $n$ is odd. Is $det (A-A^T) = 0$?

I don't know if this is true or not, I met this while working at the following problem:

"Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix where $AA^T=I_n$. Prove that $tr A \leq n$ and for $n$ odd, $det (A^2-I_n)=0$." (Romanian Olympiad, 2007).
The inequality was easy, using the known inequality $tr(AB) \cdot tr(A^TB^T) \leq tr(AA^T) \cdot tr(BB^T)$. At the second point I thought about the following relations:
$(A-I_n)(A^T+I_n)=A-A^T$ and
$(A+I_n)(A^T-I_n)=A^T-A$.

So we have that $det (A^2-I_n) \cdot det((A^T)^2-I_n)=-(det(A-A^T))^2$ and if what I say is true, than the problem is a step closer to be solved. For $n=1$ and $n=3$ it is true.

Comment: The matrix $B=A-A^t$ is such that $B^t=-B$. What is the relation between $\det B$ and $\det B^t$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Well, I think I know :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$B=A-A^T$ is skew-symmetric, so $$\det(B) = \det(B^T) = \det(-B) = (-1)^n \det(B) = -\det(B)$$

Comment: Yep, thanks :))

Comment: The matrix is skew-symmetric **and of odd order**.